# Add store code to URL's for multi language website doesn't work

Tags: magento2

Two different stores views are created where one is testsite.com as default, and the second store view is testsite.com/enfor English language. After setting up the url's, when I'm trying to prompt 'Add store codes to URL', the following error is showing: 'Invalid domain name: The input appears to be a DNS hostname but cannot match against hostname schema for TLD 'EU'; The input does not appear to be a valid URI hostname; The input does not appear to be a valid local network name'.

Edit: The production domain name ends with .eu

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I assume either your base url, or at least one of your store codes, contains characters that won't work for domains under the .eu scheme.

Hard to say though without knowing the actual data that you're using.

Comment: Stores setup: https://pasteboard.co/Lv4PmFWVFW4F.png
General -> Web: https://pasteboard.co/YzsR17RLGsMX.png 
Note: I also tried 'http://dreamsshop.eu/en/' as the 'Base URL' for both secure and not secure options, still doesn't work.

Comment: The base url shouldn't include the store view code. It gets added by Magento. Codes & URLs look good to me. Not sure if it's a problem that the link URL already includes the store code, could you remove it? If that doesn't solve it, I fear you have to look into the code and see where the message is generated.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, but I also tried the configuration without the store view codes, adding the base URL only. Unfortunately it still doesn't work and the same error gets thrown. I tried looking into the system logs but I couldn't locate anything related to the problem I am facing. Edit: I also tried using a different code ('eng' instead of 'en') but no luck

Comment: There's more than the logs: Look into the /vendor/ directory and see where the error message or INVALID_HOSTNAME_SCHEMA is located; or debug the config saving process.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your Url Options
Add Store Code to Urls should be Yes

Uncheck Use system value then select yes and save

**NOTE** clear cache after that

Comment: When I try to change the value to 'Yes', the error is prompted and the value is automatically returned to 'No'.